# Get footnote marks not raised (non-superscript) in footer only - Beamer

Tags: beamer, formatting, footnotes

In [Beamer user guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) (p. 130), we read:

> \insertfootnotemark Inserts the current footnote mark (**like a raised
>   number**).

How can I get the current footnote mark **not raised**?

In particular, I want the marks to be raised in the text body but not in the footer.

I'm able to redefine the footer with the code below:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{
  \makebox[2em][l]
{\insertfootnotemark} \footnotesize \hspace{-1em} \insertfootnotetext \par \vspace{1em}
}
```

So if I learn how to get `\insertfootnotemark` not raised, I get what I want.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{
  \makebox[2em][l]{\insertfootnotemark}\footnotesize\hspace{-1em}\insertfootnotetext\par\vspace{1em}
}

% This disables superscript for both text body and footer. 
% \makeatletter
% \renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\makebox{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}
% \makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    TEXT \footnote[frame]{Footnote}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  \makebox[2em][l]{{\usebeamercolor [fg]{footnote mark}%
                    \usebeamerfont*{footnote mark}\@thefnmark }}\footnotesize\hspace{-1em}\insertfootnotetext\par\vspace{1em}}
 \makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    TEXT \footnote[frame]{Footnote}
    \footnote{another}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```